# how to get a list with words that are next to a specific word in a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming I have a string 
`string = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'`.

What I would like to do is to get **all** the words that are next to (from the right side) the word `'i'`, so in this case `am, believe, can, believe, can`.

How could I do that in `python` ? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686809/how-to-find-word-next-to-a-word-in-python) but it only gives the first word, so in this case, `'am'`

Comment: If the answer you have linked to does the thing you want once, but you need to do it more than once, what would you do?

Comment: The (currently) last answer to your linked question actually does give the neighbouring word for each occurrence of the target word.

Comment: @AddisonLynch That is *exactly* the link OP has sourced....?

Comment: how is the question duplicate ...? I also explained the difference and what the problem is with the answer

Comment: thanks for down voting for no reason

Comment: Sorry @Idlehands, I don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a regular expression to find the words after the target word:

```
import re

word = "i"
string = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'

pat = re.compile(r'\b{}\b \b(\w+)\b'.format(word)) 
print(pat.findall(string))
# ['am', 'believe', 'can', 'believe', 'can']
```

Comment: This works. Is it possible though to replace the 'hardcoded' `i` with a `variable = 'i'`

Comment: @quant Sure `re.findall(r'\b{}\b \b(\w+)\b'.format(word), string)`

Comment: Thanks ! you could also edit the answer if you want, to the more generic one

Answer (score 2):

Simple generator method:

```
def get_next_words(text, match, sep=' '):
    words = iter(text.split(sep))
    for word in words:
        if word == match:
            yield next(words)
```

Usage:

```
text = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'
words = get_next_words(text, 'i')

for w in words:
    print(w)

# am
# believe
# can
# believe
# can
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string and get the next index of the word "i" as you iterate with `enumerate`:

```
string = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'

sl = string.split()
all_is = [sl[i + 1] for i, word in enumerate(sl[:-1]) if word == 'i']
print(all_is)
# ['am', 'believe', 'can', 'believe', 'can']
```

Note that as @PatrickHaugh pointed out, we want to be careful if "i" is the last word so we can exclude iterating over the last word completely.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with a look behind assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\bi )\w+', string)
['am', 'believe', 'can', 'believe', 'can']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = 'i am a person i believe i can fly i believe i can touch the sky'
words = [w.split()[0] for w in re.split('i +', string) if w]
print(words)
```