# How to select all the words together with punctuation, that come after another word in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following String

```
text_clean = 'i am a person. i believe i can fly. i believe i can touch the sky.'
```

and the word

```
wd = 'can'
```

I could like to get all words after the `wd` but **together** with the `.` if it exists. So I would like to get `['fly.', 'touch']`

I have tried

```
import re
re.findall(r'{} \b(\S+)\b'.format(wd),text_clean)
```

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086059/how-to-get-a-list-with-words-that-are-next-to-a-specific-word-in-a-string-in-pyt) but the solution **does not** give me the `.`'s also

Comment: Remove word boundaries, `r'{} (\S+)'.format(wd)`. See https://ideone.com/H7nyKa. Why did you add them there?

Comment: damn, that was easy. I got lost in the regex expression. You can add it as answer

Comment: No need to, "Remove word boundaries" is not long enough for an answer. You just need to read up on word boundaries to avoid such issues in future.